# Maximally distanced set of points on a high dimensional sphere

Tags: probability, geometry, optimization

How can one spread 10 points inside or on the boundary of a 256 dimensional hyper-sphere of unit radius so that the minimum of all distances between any pair of points (45 possible combinations) is maximized (or approximately maximized)?
**What should the positions of this 10 points be?**

Intuitively the points are to be spread as much as possible in the sphere and supposedly in a symmetric way.

These points could be centers of Gaussians in a Gaussian mixture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nonconvex nonlinear programming formulation.  Let $x_{i,d}$ be the coordinate of point $i$ in dimension $d$.  The problem is to maximize $z$ subject to:
\begin{align}
z &\le \sum_{d=1}^{256} (x_{i,d}-x_{j,d})^2 &&\text{for all $1 \le i<j \le 10$}\\ 
\sum_d x_{i,d}^2 &\le 1 &&\text{for all $i$}
\end{align}

By using a nonlinear programming solver, I found a solution with $z \approx 20/9$, with every pair of points achieving this distance squared.

\begin{matrix}
0.040&-.041&0.028&0.044&0.035&-.005&0.019&0.008&-.030&-.035&-.067&0.025&0.048&0.076&-.053&0.077
&0.082&-.036&-.036&-.059&0.043&0.074&0.078&0.078&-.062&0.025&-.035&0.030&-.067&-.126&-.039&
-.024&-.001&-.022&0.148&-.077&0.037&-.000&0.014&-.008&-.044&-.049&-.069&-.033&-.050&-.040&-.052
&-.096&-.046&-.104&-.004&-.026&0.058&0.035&-.090&0.086&-.026&-.029&-.132&-.067&0.052&-.044&
-.039&0.109&-.055&0.047&0.022&0.084&-.056&0.054&-.017&-.001&-.071&-.029&0.042&0.059&0.090&-.078
&0.016&-.047&-.041&-.070&0.021&0.097&0.081&0.013&0.024&-.038&-.041&0.089&0.021&-.043&-.171&
-.001&-.094&-.062&0.138&0.104&-.065&0.117&0.081&0.030&-.071&0.133&-.078&-.039&-.017&0.043&0.103
&0.027&-.089&0.083&0.014&-.016&0.044&-.062&-.025&-.114&0.033&0.026&0.074&-.027&0.083&0.062&
0.068&0.055&0.041&-.018&0.003&-.075&-.022&0.013&0.028&-.044&0.060&-.104&-.046&0.121&0.028&-.028
&-.023&-.042&0.015&-.027&0.152&-.038&0.013&0.073&0.096&0.001&-.090&0.033&-.011&0.091&0.027&
-.168&-.052&0.088&-.022&-.042&0.001&0.003&-.017&0.071&-.038&-.042&-.026&0.071&0.026&0.051&0.054
&-.081&0.060&0.015&0.011&0.030&0.109&0.054&-.008&0.086&-.052&0.072&-.039&0.019&0.031&-.022&
0.041&0.015&0.007&-.022&-.123&-.094&-.133&0.014&0.017&0.079&-.014&0.081&0.059&0.009&-.016&-.025
&-.089&0.058&0.007&0.092&-.111&0.040&0.055&0.060&-.029&-.064&0.057&-.109&-.074&-.003&0.034&
-.000&-.041&0.030&0.028&-.047&-.068&0.010&-.090&0.012&0.018&-.079&-.148&-.011&0.070&0.080&-.034
&-.086&0.002&-.008&-.065&0.060&-.030&0.044&-.153&-.066&0.112&-.091&0.069&-.008&0.056&0.000&
-.016&0.079&-.063&0.023&0.036&-.050&0.001&0.008\\
0.008&-.017&-.005&-.027&0.121&-.048&-.042&0.046&0.032&0.035&-.072&-.075&-.023&-.059&-.047&-.086
&-.121&-.008&0.043&0.015&-.042&0.016&-.094&-.032&-.149&-.052&0.028&0.102&-.073&-.016&-.084&
0.044&-.114&-.015&-.044&0.118&0.032&-.025&-.065&0.088&0.085&0.042&0.090&-.037&0.061&-.099&-.051
&-.037&-.053&0.107&-.070&-.106&0.062&-.011&0.067&-.087&-.036&0.056&0.018&0.052&0.031&-.076&
0.072&0.080&0.024&0.070&-.075&-.009&0.034&0.025&0.172&0.011&0.062&-.060&0.054&-.040&0.077&0.118
&-.043&0.061&-.036&-.001&0.099&0.071&0.113&0.010&0.037&-.040&-.022&0.072&0.000&0.013&-.041&
0.074&0.112&0.056&-.043&-.030&0.064&-.016&-.005&0.008&0.088&0.062&0.132&0.111&-.046&-.074&0.036
&-.114&-.022&0.012&-.121&-.018&0.025&-.031&0.027&0.034&0.054&-.028&0.008&-.064&-.073&0.010&
-.018&0.038&0.029&-.069&0.053&0.094&-.080&0.132&-.109&0.042&0.065&-.048&0.045&0.004&-.047&-.079
&-.081&0.018&0.068&0.008&0.051&-.029&0.061&-.097&-.028&-.048&-.076&0.006&0.102&-.117&0.070&
-.004&0.021&-.067&-.080&0.051&-.012&-.066&-.079&-.008&-.019&-.034&-.101&-.025&-.098&-.002&-.002
&0.087&-.083&0.021&0.028&-.091&0.000&-.075&-.040&0.045&-.051&-.133&-.026&-.087&0.007&0.072&
-.091&-.104&0.002&0.003&0.030&-.007&-.014&0.032&0.071&-.006&-.085&0.118&0.008&0.079&-.046&0.043
&0.001&-.004&0.041&-.114&0.078&-.107&0.059&-.048&0.003&0.051&-.007&0.002&0.047&-.027&0.060&
0.033&0.044&0.109&0.052&0.037&0.019&0.104&0.003&0.029&0.066&0.065&-.002&-.024&0.026&-.042&-.060
&-.060&0.058&-.064&0.034&-.048&0.115&0.045&0.040&-.040&0.082&-.033&-.019&0.007&-.107&-.033&
0.021&-.012&0.052&-.042&0.075&-.084&-.044&0.030\\
0.085&0.039&0.031&0.040&-.059&0.018&-.131&-.001&0.030&0.060&0.027&0.074&-.080&-.045&-.007&-.006
&0.012&-.035&0.018&-.002&-.129&-.089&0.044&-.021&0.080&-.017&-.011&-.029&0.065&-.048&-.022&
-.049&0.029&0.005&-.035&0.032&-.108&-.013&0.075&-.047&0.099&-.003&-.044&0.112&0.006&0.032&0.037
&0.014&0.054&0.090&0.009&0.059&-.074&-.010&-.098&-.125&0.015&-.108&0.079&-.041&0.045&-.122&
0.028&-.088&-.105&-.094&-.010&-.054&0.018&0.051&-.046&0.025&-.048&-.119&-.052&0.029&0.016&-.101
&-.055&0.032&-.087&0.076&0.085&0.055&-.054&0.039&0.004&-.014&-.022&0.050&-.042&0.012&-.074&
0.076&-.002&-.001&-.024&-.081&-.005&0.079&-.114&-.084&0.019&0.046&-.087&-.062&-.015&-.035&-.025
&0.006&0.059&-.007&0.085&-.104&-.117&0.045&-.018&0.017&-.038&-.127&-.107&-.072&-.037&0.010&
-.028&0.037&-.137&0.047&-.009&-.069&-.037&-.042&0.082&-.102&-.020&0.046&0.022&0.019&-.099&0.008
&0.075&-.029&0.005&-.020&-.065&0.089&-.026&-.000&-.084&0.067&0.052&-.029&0.029&-.050&-.078&
-.061&-.021&0.050&-.062&0.020&-.091&0.088&0.053&0.075&0.097&-.029&0.021&-.063&0.047&-.072&-.047
&0.095&0.047&0.079&0.021&-.091&-.062&-.090&-.070&0.055&-.008&-.072&-.004&0.123&0.076&-.032&
0.125&-.087&-.015&0.061&-.093&-.049&-.101&-.039&0.032&0.025&0.087&-.078&-.008&-.090&-.055&-.013
&-.065&-.021&0.047&-.050&0.019&0.009&-.025&0.036&0.050&-.043&-.068&0.002&0.028&0.055&0.079&
0.026&0.115&-.038&0.100&0.057&0.102&-.013&0.077&-.088&-.137&0.023&0.024&0.014&0.019&-.093&0.077
&0.036&0.011&-.056&0.080&0.068&-.074&0.110&-.030&0.021&0.015&-.054&0.024&0.016&0.044&0.017&
-.112&-.115&0.053&0.114&0.075&0.043&0.095&-.013\\
-.107&-.095&-.072&0.032&-.062&-.125&-.051&-.060&-.026&-.023&-.047&-.064&0.063&-.003&0.040&0.005
&-.136&0.028&0.050&0.031&-.100&0.006&0.010&0.071&-.009&-.006&0.013&0.050&-.028&-.037&0.041&
0.001&0.029&-.062&-.045&0.054&-.041&0.011&-.032&0.072&-.047&0.039&-.060&0.061&0.070&0.047&-.009
&0.007&0.008&-.123&-.047&0.051&-.143&0.014&-.043&0.070&-.096&0.058&-.067&-.011&-.096&-.057&
0.018&-.062&-.039&0.037&0.039&0.018&0.138&0.028&0.020&-.109&0.029&-.007&0.073&-.096&-.115&0.071
&0.032&0.043&-.073&0.053&-.086&-.039&0.151&-.024&-.089&0.046&-.009&-.026&0.074&0.072&0.069&
-.066&-.073&0.112&0.013&-.009&0.044&-.018&-.110&0.070&-.027&0.005&0.028&-.067&0.128&0.066&-.049
&0.014&0.028&-.120&0.079&0.055&0.101&0.002&-.008&0.070&0.022&-.004&0.038&-.079&0.068&0.078&
-.018&0.038&-.002&0.041&-.014&-.015&-.038&-.054&-.061&-.040&-.125&0.049&-.018&-.019&0.103&-.023
&-.081&0.011&0.078&0.073&0.050&0.106&-.015&-.005&-.037&0.027&0.014&0.009&-.025&0.089&-.026&
0.077&0.014&-.071&0.108&0.058&-.058&-.046&0.067&-.105&0.003&0.111&0.081&-.063&0.023&0.050&-.014
&-.053&-.043&0.085&0.021&-.007&0.063&-.005&-.029&-.119&0.073&0.077&0.006&0.127&-.002&0.082&
-.069&-.029&0.038&-.048&0.049&0.039&0.119&0.032&-.029&-.077&-.078&-.070&0.094&-.077&0.129&-.009
&-.032&-.072&-.084&-.096&-.103&-.018&-.037&0.026&-.068&-.112&-.005&-.040&-.053&0.066&-.021&
-.097&0.042&0.040&0.037&-.026&-.124&-.056&-.010&0.044&-.083&-.025&0.003&0.073&-.012&0.122&0.009
&-.020&0.093&-.042&-.101&-.041&-.020&-.091&0.077&-.051&-.002&0.009&0.049&0.094&-.031&0.083&
-.054&-.059&-.028&-.012&-.038&0.044&0.050&-.051\\
-.011&0.092&-.015&0.098&-.013&0.057&0.061&-.076&-.096&0.062&0.016&-.082&-.009&0.034&-.108&0.010
&0.055&0.016&-.013&-.060&0.054&-.096&-.037&-.025&0.012&0.007&-.065&0.012&0.098&-.045&0.050&
-.028&0.063&0.104&0.122&-.009&0.060&-.106&0.053&-.065&-.028&-.089&-.035&-.095&0.042&0.041&0.109
&0.059&0.051&-.010&0.073&0.066&0.103&0.063&0.074&0.090&0.067&-.026&0.090&0.037&0.085&0.047&
-.031&0.071&0.025&-.111&-.062&-.046&-.114&0.004&-.029&0.087&0.089&0.110&0.002&-.034&0.087&0.098
&-.083&-.008&0.007&0.050&0.020&-.105&0.009&0.039&-.005&0.026&-.041&-.070&-.055&-.062&0.031&
-.099&0.014&0.052&0.046&0.009&0.062&-.065&-.029&0.005&0.002&-.030&-.022&-.079&-.044&-.062&-.040
&0.061&-.113&-.003&0.065&-.021&0.016&-.049&0.003&-.107&-.055&0.126&-.092&0.028&0.016&0.087&
-.013&-.018&0.038&0.035&-.089&-.001&0.008&0.030&-.050&0.074&-.098&0.024&-.085&0.121&0.111&-.012
&0.032&0.002&-.072&-.113&-.047&-.055&0.007&0.002&0.118&0.050&0.100&0.051&0.059&0.001&-.046&
0.107&0.076&0.028&0.020&0.075&0.025&-.038&-.009&-.109&-.119&-.095&0.024&-.032&-.046&-.102&-.062
&-.012&-.052&-.025&-.050&0.034&0.003&0.008&-.038&0.003&-.011&-.001&-.019&-.057&-.095&-.113&
0.045&0.057&0.007&-.057&0.027&0.036&0.056&0.045&0.014&-.053&-.007&0.015&0.022&0.065&-.112&-.091
&0.078&-.030&0.043&-.019&0.092&-.127&-.102&-.025&-.107&0.053&-.105&-.071&-.053&0.087&0.016&
-.038&-.019&-.035&-.049&0.102&-.026&0.125&0.013&-.025&-.013&-.014&0.086&-.045&-.053&-.105&-.037
&-.032&0.010&-.039&-.132&0.023&0.095&-.007&-.028&0.075&-.084&0.106&-.054&0.036&0.001&0.031&
-.024&-.026&-.035&0.044&0.013&0.118&0.039&0.057\\
-.083&0.058&0.104&-.149&-.086&0.042&0.023&-.070&0.166&0.042&0.060&-.038&0.070&0.001&0.080&0.043
&0.092&0.003&0.023&0.077&0.111&-.073&-.059&-.026&0.082&0.068&-.032&0.039&-.015&0.077&0.072&
-.054&0.015&-.023&0.018&0.026&0.052&0.120&-.005&0.053&-.005&0.113&0.041&0.001&-.077&-.102&-.039
&0.080&-.085&0.032&0.045&0.069&-.033&0.014&-.100&0.078&-.102&-.025&0.066&-.051&-.009&0.033&
0.000&-.035&0.097&-.091&0.087&-.083&-.055&-.077&0.008&-.080&-.040&0.011&-.078&-.012&-.044&0.079
&-.050&-.022&0.054&0.031&0.031&-.054&-.050&-.056&0.040&0.010&0.061&0.001&-.018&-.039&0.008&
0.100&-.054&-.037&0.077&-.047&0.032&-.028&-.027&-.003&0.045&-.006&-.022&0.074&-.102&0.015&0.079
&-.037&-.054&0.016&-.017&-.070&-.137&0.091&0.022&0.019&0.021&0.130&0.108&-.019&-.072&-.104&
-.032&-.122&-.094&-.112&-.035&-.053&-.004&-.047&0.013&-.003&0.005&0.018&0.047&-.034&0.034&0.008
&-.004&0.012&-.083&0.036&-.024&-.092&0.019&-.106&0.022&-.060&0.002&0.100&0.006&-.073&0.136&
0.072&-.107&0.005&0.067&-.099&0.033&0.070&0.099&0.019&0.019&0.001&-.016&-.056&0.025&0.002&-.085
&0.099&-.004&-.034&-.005&0.048&-.100&0.119&0.091&-.012&0.033&0.006&0.053&0.039&-.005&0.006&
-.019&0.038&-.001&-.133&0.084&0.061&-.021&-.005&-.028&0.138&0.074&-.074&-.040&0.039&0.036&0.048
&-.067&0.011&-.128&0.122&-.112&0.057&-.027&-.017&-.033&-.101&0.065&0.081&0.046&-.035&0.003&
0.059&-.008&0.029&-.088&0.042&0.001&-.036&0.022&-.018&0.090&-.018&0.020&0.060&0.051&0.041&-.027
&0.029&-.094&0.011&-.055&-.094&0.025&0.082&0.075&-.034&-.034&-.069&-.042&0.076&-.056&-.040&
0.009&0.092&-.043&-.053&-.046&-.094&0.010&0.109\\
0.039&0.045&-.094&-.049&-.014&0.088&0.012&0.112&-.028&-.100&0.079&-.007&-.060&-.076&-.006&-.082
&0.024&0.016&-.037&0.049&0.099&0.076&-.014&-.037&-.076&-.044&0.021&-.051&-.103&0.117&-.011&
0.070&0.049&0.020&-.110&-.036&-.003&0.021&-.075&0.034&0.077&0.053&-.057&-.081&-.035&0.011&-.014
&-.056&0.098&-.109&-.011&-.012&-.074&-.043&0.018&0.016&0.046&0.035&-.016&0.053&0.034&0.096&
-.051&-.101&0.029&0.130&0.035&0.087&0.018&-.045&-.002&0.062&0.026&0.114&0.076&0.051&0.017&-.089
&0.040&-.103&0.110&0.021&-.122&0.030&-.081&0.037&0.052&0.109&0.074&-.071&-.018&-.115&0.080&
0.049&-.081&-.059&-.125&0.032&-.103&-.028&0.014&-.081&0.000&-.077&-.033&0.056&0.030&0.010&-.008
&-.005&0.024&0.058&-.105&0.088&-.111&-.006&-.011&-.012&-.016&0.064&-.012&0.103&0.107&0.015&
-.011&0.077&0.012&0.062&0.031&0.021&0.100&0.026&0.099&-.014&0.028&0.030&-.094&-.084&-.093&-.001
&0.118&0.011&-.034&0.018&-.066&0.095&0.107&0.111&0.042&-.065&-.090&-.020&0.040&-.020&-.061&
0.043&-.097&-.099&-.101&-.012&-.062&-.041&-.045&0.082&0.036&-.108&-.070&0.013&-.023&-.056&0.026
&-.015&0.072&-.000&0.110&-.090&0.044&-.081&0.023&0.025&0.085&0.009&0.026&0.014&-.004&-.098&
0.018&0.023&0.010&-.025&0.096&0.013&0.013&-.060&0.110&-.060&-.009&-.100&0.008&-.064&0.077&0.010
&0.021&0.045&-.068&-.034&0.043&-.054&0.062&0.018&0.058&0.111&0.113&0.044&-.008&0.075&-.049&
-.102&-.106&-.055&-.003&0.027&0.012&0.001&0.013&0.005&-.012&0.006&0.054&0.061&-.026&0.062&-.041
&0.095&0.090&-.003&0.045&-.005&-.042&-.013&-.022&-.124&0.008&0.040&-.017&-.123&0.018&0.071&
0.067&-.014&-.064&0.011&-.062&0.068&-.083&0.074\\
0.006&0.077&-.054&-.021&0.128&-.097&0.111&-.022&-.029&-.073&0.036&-.017&0.020&0.072&0.058&0.133
&-.096&-.011&0.026&-.005&0.068&-.025&0.000&-.018&-.021&0.034&-.023&-.047&0.024&-.032&0.078&
-.032&-.069&0.077&-.007&0.076&-.071&0.007&0.017&0.019&-.059&-.049&0.137&0.078&-.071&0.028&-.066
&0.011&-.061&0.027&-.044&-.069&-.031&-.014&0.030&-.031&0.061&0.016&-.105&-.133&0.004&0.053&
-.023&-.050&-.064&0.036&-.082&0.056&-.020&0.001&-.003&-.001&-.038&0.034&-.011&-.094&0.088&-.079
&0.096&0.091&0.002&-.073&-.072&-.104&-.064&-.051&0.026&-.073&0.020&-.044&0.073&0.017&0.000&
0.025&0.110&0.041&-.042&0.062&-.006&-.094&0.009&0.102&-.077&-.043&-.016&0.098&0.125&-.077&0.007
&0.042&0.047&-.085&0.013&0.014&0.005&-.062&-.029&0.106&-.058&-.116&0.070&-.040&0.027&-.120&
0.001&0.021&0.077&-.034&0.024&-.036&0.091&-.064&-.087&0.062&0.001&0.121&0.010&-.031&-.029&0.053
&-.007&0.001&-.005&-.045&-.062&-.039&-.042&0.010&-.101&0.100&0.095&-.076&-.060&0.099&-.034&
0.059&0.059&0.148&-.027&-.102&0.056&0.092&-.009&-.027&0.009&0.040&-.005&0.113&0.020&0.012&0.009
&-.071&-.054&-.054&-.042&0.013&-.006&-.060&0.071&0.093&-.000&0.008&0.113&-.058&-.034&0.069&
0.007&-.013&-.013&0.118&0.014&0.089&0.017&0.142&0.025&-.038&0.057&0.047&-.102&-.007&0.041&-.054
&0.051&0.002&0.088&0.100&0.077&0.080&-.053&-.113&0.082&0.068&0.012&-.023&-.127&-.067&-.055&
0.098&-.026&-.046&-.069&-.026&0.094&-.071&0.083&0.062&0.093&0.042&-.080&-.099&-.000&-.024&0.086
&0.062&-.064&0.090&0.104&0.005&-.054&0.002&-.005&0.043&-.036&-.015&0.081&-.055&0.059&-.119&
0.038&0.008&0.002&0.004&-.029&0.036&-.024&-.076\\
-.006&-.082&0.028&-.023&-.009&-.011&-.078&0.094&0.002&0.128&-.063&0.080&-.020&0.067&0.021&-.123
&0.053&0.113&-.075&0.041&-.067&0.107&-.011&0.019&0.080&-.064&0.094&-.089&-.023&-.011&0.031&
0.019&0.062&-.124&-.025&-.108&0.090&-.076&-.013&-.059&-.037&-.074&-.007&-.082&-.081&0.026&0.076
&0.002&-.033&0.096&0.007&-.018&0.081&-.045&0.075&-.044&0.016&0.002&-.018&0.098&-.056&0.111&
-.081&0.130&-.040&-.020&-.039&0.031&0.123&-.017&-.017&0.045&0.025&-.115&-.091&0.087&-.113&-.040
&0.101&-.041&0.033&0.004&-.007&0.002&-.095&0.012&-.085&-.109&-.098&-.007&0.021&0.109&0.008&
-.088&0.064&0.025&-.037&-.028&-.096&0.020&0.062&-.070&-.054&-.087&-.014&0.014&-.107&0.036&-.023
&0.079&0.035&-.028&0.031&0.094&0.052&0.046&-.019&0.019&0.006&-.031&-.102&0.093&-.081&0.062&
0.012&-.111&0.063&0.082&0.039&0.103&0.004&0.016&0.061&-.037&0.029&-.032&0.114&-.083&0.099&0.017
&0.051&0.022&-.034&0.029&0.050&-.081&-.038&-.019&-.046&-.068&0.010&-.069&-.056&-.020&0.045&
-.112&0.029&-.095&-.049&-.009&0.046&-.044&0.028&0.023&-.027&0.066&0.053&-.039&-.020&0.094&0.015
&-.038&0.041&-.042&-.035&0.063&-.033&0.101&-.070&-.086&0.009&0.069&-.057&-.023&0.053&0.072&
-.015&0.068&0.034&0.055&-.077&0.009&0.038&-.062&-.113&0.056&-.041&0.019&-.004&0.044&-.016&0.051
&0.043&0.070&0.095&-.041&-.107&0.087&-.022&0.016&0.027&-.008&-.111&0.055&0.056&-.045&-.084&
0.094&-.084&-.005&-.069&-.045&0.049&-.093&-.054&0.022&0.002&-.012&0.021&-.076&-.093&-.110&0.039
&0.036&0.010&-.029&-.001&-.079&-.079&-.059&0.091&0.095&-.074&0.016&-.104&-.139&-.049&-.009&
0.013&0.043&0.094&-.062&-.024&0.002&-.016&-.014\\
0.029&-.077&0.048&0.056&-.041&0.080&0.077&-.031&-.021&-.095&0.030&0.103&-.009&-.068&0.023&0.029
&0.034&-.086&0.001&-.086&-.038&0.005&0.082&-.010&0.062&0.050&0.012&-.018&0.122&0.120&-.116&
0.052&-.063&0.039&-.022&-.076&-.047&0.061&0.030&-.086&-.040&0.018&0.003&0.077&0.136&0.055&0.010
&0.014&0.069&-.004&0.043&-.016&0.051&-.004&0.067&-.053&0.055&0.022&0.085&0.063&-.090&-.042&
0.107&-.054&0.128&-.004&0.084&-.082&-.085&-.023&-.085&-.039&-.035&0.060&-.013&0.049&-.103&0.020
&-.054&-.004&0.031&-.091&0.032&0.047&-.010&-.019&-.005&0.083&0.079&0.006&-.056&0.035&0.089&
-.069&0.006&-.127&-.002&-.012&0.074&0.034&0.119&0.024&0.074&-.003&0.112&-.106&0.049&0.078&-.081
&-.073&0.083&0.073&-.044&-.024&0.123&0.026&0.059&-.032&0.030&-.040&0.015&0.078&-.038&-.101&
0.038&-.015&-.027&-.035&-.003&0.031&-.023&-.009&0.023&0.062&0.054&-.104&0.005&-.014&-.109&0.056
&-.080&-.007&0.061&0.040&-.040&0.044&-.086&0.032&0.018&-.006&-.016&-.005&-.084&0.000&-.033&
-.014&0.077&0.014&0.147&0.061&0.061&-.017&-.088&-.020&0.041&0.090&0.040&0.081&0.047&0.023&0.106
&-.013&0.015&-.045&-.060&0.091&-.019&0.028&0.069&-.090&-.079&-.035&-.053&-.097&-.025&-.035&
-.042&0.031&-.070&0.048&-.008&-.097&0.025&-.099&-.098&-.064&0.017&0.042&-.036&0.003&-.037&0.039
&0.057&-.059&-.041&0.039&0.126&0.033&0.090&0.047&0.016&0.046&0.049&0.059&0.137&-.105&0.017&
-.072&0.084&-.029&0.061&-.121&-.059&0.029&-.057&-.043&-.023&0.012&0.021&0.047&0.018&0.068&-.011
&-.059&-.116&0.140&0.091&0.111&0.064&-.114&-.044&0.081&0.012&0.091&0.014&0.097&0.065&-.002&
0.058&0.005&0.033&-.026&-.000&-.085&-.028&-.124\\
\end{matrix}